# How should I name functions that do the same thing but in different modules?

Tags: python

So, I have two scripts temperature.py and rain.py. These two scripts do the same thing: open a file, update it and then save it. The purpose of the functions is the same but the functions do it differently for each script.

My question is should I give the same name, ex. `update()`, to both scripts, all it should be different ?

I am going to import them like below:

```
import temperature
import rain
```

Comment: If they do the same thing, they should have the same name. If the two functions have code that is identical (or nearly so), they should be removed and integrated into a single function in an appropriate location. If you do keep both with the same name, make sure not to do `from module import *`.

Comment: I've provided an answer below but I'd like to echo @TigerhawkT3. Why do the scripts do the same thing but in a different way? Shouldn't they share some code which can imported into each one? Remember the DRY principal - Don't Repeat Yourself!

Comment: The code is not identical, so I can't create just one function. As for import, I mentioned on purpose how I will do the it.

Comment: @Ewan: There are differences that can't be formed into one function.

Comment: How "not identical" are we talking here? "Update a camera's sensor" vs "update a label in Tkinter"? Or "update the temperature field based on input pin 1" vs "update the rain field based on input pin 2"?

Comment: @evil_inside - that's cool. I'm not questioning your code was just wondering :-) in that case i'd personally go with my descriptive naming convention below.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: The columns of the files are not the same and the processing of them is different.

Comment: If they're truly different and merely have similar overall descriptions (i.e., "update"), then simply make sure not to `import *` for these modules.

Comment: There are examples for e.g. the sql packages and the serialization packages.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to use the same names, especially if you are not up to `from temperature import *` or similar nastinesses.  The way you write you want to do it, there is no problem by calling `rain.update()` and `temperature.update()`.

But maybe you should reconsider if your two "modules" shouldn't be better two classes which inherit from each other or at least from a common base class.  If you want two things to "do the same, but differently", then overriding an inherited behaviour is the object-oriented way to do it.  Maybe the two `update()`s even have something in common which both need to do (which is a very typical case); that could then be done in a base class then.

And even if you now would answer "no, they have nothing in common", I think I feel the *idea* of them having something in common on a more theoretical level.  In that case, maybe later versions of your software would benefit from the different architecture I propose.

Answer (score 0):

What about making the function specific and descriptive to the context?

- `from temperature import update_temperature`
- `from rain import update_rain`

Naming like this provides a lesser chance of naming conflicts (like both files having an `update()`, or even a third-party package having it's own `update()`).

It provides a clear understanding of what exactly your code is doing; updating the temperature (not the units `temperature.update_units`, or the location `temperature.update_location`) and states it.

Comment: I don't like that at all.  Good languages know naming scopes for a reason.  If you use names like `update_temperature` you double the naming, effectively, as the function then is `temperature.update_temperature()`.

Comment: @Alfe: That's exactly what I am thinking about, it seems redundant.

Comment: @Alfe - I'm inside the `temperature` module but what am I updating? The temperature? The units to describe the temperature? The location of the temperature? Specifying _exactly_ what is being updated provides easier to read and more understandable code

Comment: @Ewan Yeah, but `X.update_X()` is redundant.  I would not object against an `X.update_Y()` like a `rain.update_location()`.

Comment: @Alfe True and as a method to an object where you're updating the instance I don't disagree. But as a function in a module it's not always obvious what you're doing. E.g. `from datetime import datetime` It's personal preference and we can agree to disagree but I would like to avoid user error of naming scopes; make it easier to read for future developers; and to me it's more logical. Looks like I might be in the minority though...

Comment: @Ewan But you have a point there.  Modules are rather a grouping concept of loosely connected things while classes reflect closed entities.  Different rules apply.